# Save a mesh posed with armature

Tags: animation, mesh, armature

I have a mesh parented to an armature with animation. I wonder how I can export the mesh from blender at any pose I want, and if there is an option to save these poses in my blend project so that I can save the mesh deformations at certain poses and then delete the armature. If anyone could please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store reusable poses you can use [pose library](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Rigging/Posing/Pose_Library) this would still require a rig to restore.
[image]

When you export to e.g. to a .obj-file you could store the mesh in different fixed poses without the armatures.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the pose but get rid of the armature by applying the armature modifier while the mesh is posed. You can also create a duplicate of the mesh and apply it's modifier instead, if you'd like to have a posed version and still keep the version with the armature on it.